# Application working on emulator but not working on actual device

Tags: android

I am testing facebook Single-Sign-On application. 
I am using android platform 2.2 and api level 8. I have similarly created emulator with the same configuration. It is working fine in emulator. But when i test it on actual device that is HTC Desire HD ver 2.2 froyo updated. It opens up a dialog with facebook as title and shows loading screen then disappears.

I am unable to understand the reason for such behavior.

Please help me on this.

Regards,

Pankaj

Comment: Is there an error message in the logs?

Comment: Please post code and error logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the debug on device working and see the error that appears in LogCat.You can find instructions oh how to use debug on device [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: thanks for replying . I have enabled debug on device. When i check the Log it shows 05-06 13:13:20.288: DEBUG/Facebook-authorize(25090): Login failed: invalid_key

Answer (score 0):

You can plug in your device using the usb cable (making sure usb debugging is on in the options).

then debug your application and you will see what the cause is in the debugging console.

I suspect tho your problem is to do with how you are transferring the apk file to the phone (it needs to be signed for facebook SSO to work and you need to have set the key correctly in your facebook app).

See here for more information:
http://www.juje.me/2011/04/export-the-signature-of-your-android-app-for-facebook-api-use/